# Keeping a server "live"

Tags: tcp, erlang

I was creating a server in Erlang and I had a problem that I couldn't solve. I have my server and a client, the server listen the client send a message output it in the console and then does nothing. I was trying to make him "live" waiting the messages of a lot of clients and answering them.

Here's the code

```
init(PortNumber) ->
server_logger:init(),

% default options = [data type, socket work mode]
DefaultOptions = [binary, {packet, 0}, {active, false}, {reuseaddr, true}],

case gen_tcp:listen(PortNumber, DefaultOptions) of
     {ok, ListenSocket} ->
        server_logger:print_fmsg("Listening on port: ~B", [PortNumber]),
        server_logger:print_newline(),
        server_logger:print_fmsg(": ", []),
        case gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket) of
            {ok, Socket} ->
                {ok, Bin} = do_recv(Socket, []),
                ok = gen_tcp:close(Socket),
                Bin;
            {error, closed} ->
                server_logger:print_msg("The connection is closed and cannot listen.")
        end;
    {error, Reason} -> 
        server_logger:print_fmsg("Cannot listen, cause: ~w", [Reason])
 end.

do_recv(Socket, Bs) -> 
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of
        {ok, B} -> 
            case B of 
                %do_recv(Socket,  [Bs, B]);
                _ -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "Hellllooooooooooo")
            end;
        {error, closed} -> 
            {ok, list_to_binary(Bs)}
    end.
```

I don't know if what I'm doing it's right, e.g: I have the console of the server, I init him with `server:init(8889)`, in the cmd I type telnet localhost 8889 and them I press enter it says Hellllooooooooooo. Or I can do with my client in Erlang too, but the point is how to make the server sending the messages for who connects to him, via telnet or client interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I undestand your intentions well, here is some general tips:

1. To keep the server "live" the receiving function must be tail-recursive. So basically the function should: wait for a signal, when it gets one - serve it and call itself recursively again. To make it stop, just specify a special message that will stop the recursion when it gets to the function. Very general code (gets the message and prints an according response to the screen):

   `serveSignal() ->`

   ```
       receive 
           hello -> io:format("Hello World!"),
                    serveSignal();
           bye   -> io:format("Bye World!"),
                    serveSignal();
           stop  -> {"Server stopped", ok};
           _     -> unknownMessage,
                    serveSignal()
       end.
   ```
2. To make server response differently to different requests/users your serving functions need to receive, for example, tuples with some proper arguments. For example, let one of your receiver functions get the signal, determine IP of the sender and then send a tuple {IP, signal} to another function which will send a reply (adequate to the signal) to the IP given. So the second method general code may look like:

`receive`

```
    {IP, signalOne} -> replyingFunctionPID ! {IP, responseToSignalOne};
    {IP, signalTwo} -> replyingFunctionPID ! {IP, responseToSignalTwo}
end
```

Comment: Well, that is a nice approach, but it's not simple receive, because i'm using the [{active, false}] option, and as you can see the commented line calls the function of receive recursively (You can see the last function do_recv) `do_recv(Socket,  [Bs, B]);` and does not work ):